# Can't download images from S3 nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I am using AWS SDK to download images from S3 in NodeJS. I have IAM role set up so I can initialize s3 directly and use it. This is the code I used to initialize the S3 instance:

```
export class MediaServiceImpl implements MediaService {
  private s3: AWS.S3;

  constructor() {
    this.s3 = this.getS3Client();
  }
  private getS3Client(): AWS.S3 {
    AWS.config.region = config.s3Config.region;
    const s3 = new AWS.S3();
    return s3;
  }

}
```

Then in the code for download images, if I use the s3 instance in constructor, it works, returns an URL that show the image.

```
getReadSignedUrl(key: string, bucket_name: string): string {
    return this.s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
      Bucket: bucket_name,
      Key: key,
      Expires: EXPIRED_TIME
    });
  }
```

But if I get a new instance from getS3Client, it doesn't work, just return the same URL for every images: https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com

```
getReadSignedUrl(key: string, bucket_name: string): string {
  const s3 = this.getS3Client();
  return s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
    Bucket: bucket_name,
    Key: key,
    Expires: EXPIRED_TIME
  });
}
```

I have searched around for this problem but it seems no one has encountered the same thing like me.

Comment: What does "works" mean, what does "doesn't work" mean in your case? Both snippets do not actually downloading anything, they generate a presigned url.

Comment: @luk2302 ah this is BE code. Doesn't work means the presigned is just: https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com. And works means the FE receives a full working URL that can show the image. I have edited the question as well.

Comment: That's not a pre-signed URL at all. It's just the S3 endpoint in Singapore. Suggests that you are not actually calling the getReadSignedUrl() function at all, or that your code is otherwise broken and is not logging/returning the signed URL that it actually created.

Comment: What is or where did you find `getS3Client` in the docs? I've not seen this before and it doesn't seem to be part of the S3 Javascript SDK?

Comment: @bendataclear getS3Client() is the OP's own code, in the MediaServiceImpl class.

Comment: @jarmod yes if I create a new instance of s3 for every new request, it doesn't return a correct pre-signed url. But if I use s3 instance in the constructor, it does return a correct one.

Comment: Are you saying that the URL returned each time is literally `https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com`? Or is it a legitimate pre-signed URL (with access key, expiry time etc.), but that each time you call the function to get a pre-signed URL for a different object, the function returns the exact same pre-signed URL?

Comment: @jarmod yes if I use the getS3Client() to create s3 instance then get the pre-signed url, it always returns https://s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com, not a legitimate pre-signed URL (with access key, expiry time etc.). 
But if I use the s3 instance in the constructor, it works, returns legitimate URL.
And one more case I tried this morning: I commented out the constructor and the private s3: AWS.S3; line. Now every time I have some operation with S3, I use getS3Client() to create a new instance, and this works.

Comment: Strange, I can't repro this with your code with Node v14 and aws-sdk 2.804.0. I mildly altered your code to remove the export and the TypeScript-ness of it to make it simple to run under Node.js. Works fine and yields reasonable pre-signed URLs for both methods.

Comment: @jarmod maybe because I am running this on EC2 AWS. And the credentials has been configured using IAM roles by the devops team. Before I need to use ECSCredential but now I can create AWS S3 directly and use it.

Comment: Doubt running with IAM role on EC2 would cause this. What is `config`? Where does that come from and how does it change over time? Perhaps it's valid when MediaServiceImpl is constructed but somehow invalid later.

Comment: @jarmod I am just a junior so don't know much about this. But after I commented out constructor and the class variable private s3: AWS.S3; and use the getS3Client() to create new s3 instance every time I have to do something with S3. This works. Maybe because I can only have 1 instance at a time?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239499/discussion-between-jarmod-and-thuan-nguyen).